# Travelling to Schengen countries frequently

Tags: schengen, south-african-citizens

I am a South African currently residing in the UK but will be travelling to Europe (Schengen) for business/tourism once a month.

I already have 2 Schengen visas each only valid for 3 weeks with single entry.

How can I get a Schengen visa with multiple entries and is valid for a longer period? My trips are planned for the next 3 months.

I have showed the consulates that I am going to other Schengen countries in the near future but they said the visits must be within 15 days of each other. (A rule I can't find anywhere on a website dealing with Schengen visas.)

I can't go up to London, waste time at the consulate or visa centre and pay the visa and extra fees every time. Sometimes I won't even have my passport returned to me in time for the next trip.

What should/can I do?

Comment: Have you tried applying for multiple entry visa?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there isn't much you can do, Schengen consulates cannot refuse a visa without providing a specific reason and offering a way to appeal their decision but they can pretty much issue what they want without explanation. There are multi-year multiple entry visas with up to 5 years validity specifically intended for people in your position (UK residents, frequent business trips) but you're unlikely to get one the first time around.

The best you can do is use the visas you already have, scrupulously obeying the rules and after you've shown you are a reliable applicant by using several visas correctly, you stand a better chance of getting a multiple entry visa. When you apply, do ask for it (there is a box for that on the application form) and provide as much documentation as possible (regarding your situation in the UK and why you need to make those trips).

In practice, the country to which you apply probably plays a small role as well, some countries routinely issue multiple entry visas to UK residents, others are more stingy. But there isn't much you can do about that without changing your plans as you need to apply to the country you want to visit.

Comment: The OP already has two Schengen visas, so he would not be applying "the first time around", no?

Comment: @jpatokal Yes, but the way I read the question, he seemed to be (understandably) disappointed that he had to get these two visas instead of a single multiple entry visa and he hasn't used any of them yet. After that, there is still no guarantee, it depends on the consulate, the country of origin, etc.